# cx_Oracle not installing on Oracle Linux

Tags: python, linux, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to install cx_Oracle on Oracle Linux with the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking cx-Oracle
  Running setup.py egg_info for package cx-Oracle
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-root/cx-Oracle/setup.py", line 183, in <module>
        raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate Oracle include files")
    distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate Oracle include files
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/cx-Oracle/setup.py", line 183, in <module>

    raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate Oracle include files")

distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate Oracle include files

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/cx-Oracle
```

This is my log file: https://gist.github.com/beckah/695810cc9535a9734878

I have legitimately tried almost all answers to similar questions, mostly pertaining to similar problems with cx_Oracle and Centos, and have not come across anything that's worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial worked like a charm and saved my life: http://ubuntugeeknerd.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-install-oxoracle-in-rhel-64-bit.html